# Provisioning profile issue in Xcode 7.1.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ipa

Earlier I was using Xcode 7 it used to show me the provisioning profile for the **IPA** file which I selected under build settings. But now after update to 7.1.1 whenever I make **IPA** file then it always show me `iOS Team provisioning` under provisioning profile section even I have selected the correct provisioning profile.

See screenshot:

[image]

Please tell me how to resolve the issue.

**Edit:**

In iOS Team Provisioning profile all the UDIDs are added which were previously added by me on developer account.

Comment: Please suggest me something.

Answer (score 2):

In `developer.apple.com`:

Go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Provisioning Profiles

Delete any provisioning profiles that are no longer needed.

Pay careful attention to those that match your app's bundle ID, for example, `com.yourdomain.yourappname`.

Make sure you have at most one provisioning profile for Development and at most one provisioning profile for Distribution.

**Download each provisioning profile and double-click on it in Finder so that it gets installed.**

---

In Xcode:

Go to Your Target > Build Settings > Code Signing

Set all values to be **iOS Developer.**

Go to Your Target > Build Settings > Provisioning Profile

Set all values to be **Automatic.**

---

In Xcode:

To test the changes, create an archive using Product > Archive.

After the archive is built, open the Window > Organizer and Export the archive.

Choose Developer Deployment.

Choose your team.

The provisioning profile display should now be correct for your app in the Summary window, the one that you have shown in your question.

Comment: i want to export ipa for developer deployment why for app store distribution?

Comment: It doesn't have to be for app store distribution. You can also test it with developer deployment.

Comment: i choose my provisioning profile under build settings & then after archive i choose developer deployment then it does not show the correct provisioning profile

Comment: Did you set the provisioning profile to **Automatic?**

Comment: No i don't set automatic.till xcode 7 it was working fine now it does not work

Comment: your approach does not work.it is still showing me iOS team provisioning profile.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include three new items: ensure at most one provisioning profile for each type, download each one and install it, set the code signing identity to iOS Developer.

Comment: why should i choose for app store?earlier in xocde 7.0 i used select developer for deployment

Comment: I removed the suggestion to test with an app store deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps.
1.Open Xcode 
2. then goto Xcode section
3. Select Preferences 
4. Account
5. Select your account details
6. Click View Detail
7 .Sync details.

Comment: there no such option to sync details in xcode 7.1.1